# Yii2 update pjax list view on link (category) click

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

In my index I have the following setup to list my categories, I want to update my pjax/list view when one of the category links is clicked. When the link is clicked it needs to send the category id to an ajax action that will provide my pjax/listview with data which has the same category id.

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($datacategoryProvider->models as $model) {

    echo '<li><a class="category-link">' . $model->name . '</a></li>';
}
?>  
</ul>
```

And then my pjax/list view is below

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'item_list']); ?>

<?=  ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => '_index',
]);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this javascript and it will work

```
  $this->registerJs('
  jQuery(document).pjax(".category-link", "#item_list", {
      "push": true,
      "replace": false,
      "timeout": 1000,
      "scrollTo": false
  });
  ');
```